# Pyspark Structured streaming wrap trigger under a function

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Any one has a suggestion how to efficiently wrap trigger step of structured streaming in a separate function.Here is my code :

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession

def start_streaming_job(df: DataFrame, trigger_type: str, trigger_interval: str = None):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredStreamingExample").getOrCreate()

    query = (
        df.writeStream.format("console")
        .trigger(
            once=True if trigger_type == "once" else None,
            processingTime=trigger_interval if trigger_type == "processingTime" else None,
            availableNow=True if trigger_type == "availableNow" else None,
            continuous=trigger_interval if trigger_type == "continuous" else None
        )
    )

    query.start().awaitTermination()
```

## Example usage:

start_streaming_job(df, trigger_type="once")

start_streaming_job(df, trigger_type="processingTime", trigger_interval='2 seconds')

start_streaming_job(df, trigger_type="availableNow")

start_streaming_job(df, trigger_type="continuous", trigger_interval='1 second')

I would like to wrap trigger functionality under a function so that all that cluttering can be managed in a separate function.